# Prevent Enter Key (KeyCode 13) on input element within Colorbox from closing the colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, colorbox

I have a strange problem in IE9.

If i put an input element within a colorbox (inline HTML) then press enter with said input element having focus - the colorbox closes?

This does not happen in Chrome.

Ive setup a jsfiddle to demonstrate this problem:

- Open Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rv74f/3/
- Click the **Inline HTML** link
- Click on the resulting text box to give it focus
- Press Enter on your keyboard - the Colorbox then fades out?

I cant see anything in the options to prevent / explain this beheviour?

How can i prevent Enter from closing the colorbox short of catching keypress events on all my input elements?

I've had a quick look in colorbox source and noticed parameters such as `escKey: true,` but i cant see any to explain this Enter Key issue?

**Edit:**

If i add the following into `publicMethod.close()`

```
alert("caller is " + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
```

It tells me that .close() is being called by `publicMethod.close()`

If i add the following instead (note the use of caller.caller to move further up the stack):

```
alert("caller is " + arguments.callee.caller.caller.toString());
```

I get the following:

```
---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
caller is 
function( event ) {

    // Make a writable jQuery.Event from the native event object
    event = jQuery.event.fix( event );

    var i, ret, handleObj, matched, j,
        handlerQueue = [],
        args = core_slice.call( arguments ),
        handlers = ( jQuery._data( this, "events" ) || {} )[ event.type ] || [],
        special = jQuery.event.special[ event.type ] || {};

    // Use the fix-ed jQuery.Event rather than the (read-only) native event
    args[0] = event;
    event.delegateTarget = this;

    // Call the preDispatch hook for the mapped type, and let it bail if desired
    if ( special.preDispatch && special.preDispatch.call( this, event ) === false ) {
        return;
    }

    // Determine handlers
    handlerQueue = jQuery.event.handlers.call( this, event, handlers );

    // Run delegates first; they may want to stop propagation beneath us
    i = 0;
    while ( (matched = handlerQueue[ i++ ]) && !event.isPropagationStopped() ) {
        event.currentTarget = matched.elem;

        j = 0;
        while ( (handleObj = matched.handlers[ j++ ]) && !event.isImmediatePropagationStopped() ) {

            // Triggered event must either 1) have no namespace, or
            // 2) have namespace(s) a subset or equal to those in the bound event (both can have no namespace).
            if ( !event.namespace_re || event.namespace_re.test( handleObj.namespace ) ) {

                event.handleObj = handleObj;
                event.data = handleObj.data;

                ret = ( (jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler )
                        .apply( matched.elem, args );

                if ( ret !== undefined ) {
                    if ( (event.result = ret) === false ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Call the postDispatch hook for the mapped type
    if ( special.postDispatch ) {
        special.postDispatch.call( this, event );
    }

    return event.result;
}
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

**So the colorbox.close() method is being called by a JQuery function? Now i just need to figure out why....**

The mystery deepens....

Comment: @HeavenCore Add the [tag:internet-explorer-9] tag then.

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rv74f/4/, now it works fine in IE9 too. Its just a demo, you should call a function on keypress event and check for keycode, if pressed key is an enter key than only return false, otherwise currently you can't enter any text in input field

Comment: @gaurav Cheers, but that would mean adding an event handle to every input element - an ugly workaround given that the input elements I’ll be loading are diverse and may well have event handles of their own for various reasons - that's why I said "short of catching keypress events on all my input elements" in my question.

Comment: Any solutions for this

Comment: @Bogdan Nope, not yet :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed - cant re-create the issue in colorbox v1.4.33 (2013-10-31)